# C# & .NET request: On mySQL connection my app says: “The given key was not present in the dictionary”

Tags: c#, mysql

I browsed many answers with "The given key was not present in the dictionary", but the problems were always bad usage of parameters. I'm not using any parameters and still get this error. Any help?

```
 string connection = "Server=db4free.net;Database=rmkhu;Uid=rmkrmk;Pwd=***;";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
            MySqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select * FROM drpciv_hu";

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    label7.Text = reader["kerdes"].ToString();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                label7.Text = ex.Message;

            }
```

When I run this code I get catch (Exception ex). 
ex.Message = The given key was not present in the dictionary

Comment: where do error break ?rebuild project

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is right? You sure your `drpciv_hu` table has `kerdes` column?

Comment: Is `drpciv_hu` table contains `kerdes` column?

Comment: At a guess, there's no column called `kerdes` in your result..

Comment: does it break when assigning label7.text (check 'kerdes' ) or on con.open() ?

Comment: @SonerGönül I am sure, even if I try with reader[1] it throws the same exception.

Comment: There is no problem with the table: http://i.imgur.com/23JIve9.png